# Running one process in parallel linux

Tags: python, linux, parallel-processing

I need to make sure to run two processes (python scripts) almost at the same time. But I want the program to continue until one of them is finished. I am running these processes from a C++ program using system.

Is this the right way to run script1 and script2 at the same time and continue just after script2 is finished?

```
python ./script1.py & python ./script2.py
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet won't work because it will continue as soon as `script2` finishes. `script1` may still be working at the background.

If you are using bash shell you can do the following:

```
python ./script1.py &
PID1=$!
python ./script2.py
wait $PID1
```

`$!` has the process id of the previously background command. So we run `script1` in the background, then we run `script2` until completion, and then we wait for `script1` to finish (if not already finished).